# Laravel Query builder, how to have 1 leading where and the other orwhere?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a problem with my query.

I want to filter through all Orders where user_id is the authenticated user. And run the searchquery on field number1 and field number2.

Query:

```
$query = Order::query();

$query->where('user_id', Auth()->id())
      ->where('number','LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%')
      ->orWhere('number2,'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%')
      ->with('user');
```

I want to ALWAYS check where user_id is `Auth()->id()`;

But when i run this orWhere it also gets orders from other users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Auth()->id() is working properly i already checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
$query = Order::query();

$query->where('user_id', Auth()->id())
      ->where(function ($query) use ($searchquery) {
            $query->where('number','LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
            $query->orWhere('number2,'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
        })
     ->with('user');
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i needed. Wil Approve this answer when i can.